# How to iterate over Map<String, List<MyObject>> in the jsp using struts tag library?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-tags

On Backend side I have a Map:

```
SortedMap<String, List<MyObject>> myMap = new TreeMap<>()
```

`MyObject` has `private String name` field with pulic getter and setter

On jsp I have:

```
<nested:iterate property="myMap" id="map">
     <bean:write name="map" property="key"/>
      <nested:iterate property="listElement" id="value">
          <bean:write name="value" property="name"/>
      </nested:iterate>
</nested:iterate>
```

But I see error:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property: "otherBean.MyMap(API).listElement" of bean: "MyBeanForm"
```

How could I fix it ?

Comment: This is not Struts 2. Is that a typo in your first need iterator?

Comment: @Dave Newton oh sorry - it might be first struts . typo is fixed

Comment: There's no way to answer without context; we have no way of knowing what's in your form, how everything is exposed (or not), etc.

Comment: If to remove **<nested:iterate property="listElement" id="value">
          <bean:write name="value" property="name"/>
      </nested:iterate>**  - error is foes away. Is it make sense ?

Comment: @Dave Newton any ideas ? How to improve my answer to make it possible to answer ?

Comment: @Dave Newton the challenge here that map value is a list and we need to iterate over that list somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works

```
<nested:iterate property="myMap" id="entry">
     <bean:write name="entry" property="key"/>
      <nested:iterate property="value" name="entry" id="obj">
          <bean:write name="obj" property="name"/>
      </nested:iterate>
</nested:iterate>
```

Comment: You asked that I look at this question, it seems resolved. If there are still issues please let me know.